# Two styles for a VBulletin site

Tags: css, vbulletin

I am trying to help a friend style his VBulletin site with a forum. He wants some of the sections to have a site-like layout with a large header, and the forum sections to have a different more forum-like style.

Is there a way I can set different css for different pages of a VBulletin site.

I am new at VBulletin, this might be trivial.

Thanks in advance!

Mladen

Answer (score 0):

in forum manager (from admincp) you can choose different styles from each section in the edit panel.

you can also override users chosen style

(sorry for my poor english)